# executeUpdate throws error when writing to openfire db

Tags: java, oracle, openfire, bonecp

Trying to insert into a table present in openfire db:

```
..
..
Connection con = new Connection();
Statment stmt = null;
try{
 stmt.executeUpdate("insert into utable values ('a','a');");
}
catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}
...
..
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:202)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:45)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:933)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1075)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1603)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:308)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.StatementHandle.executeUpdate(StatementHandle.java:497)
```

I tried to insert manually to db using that query and I could insert successfully. I'm using BoneCP connection pooling. I've no problem reading from the dbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into utable values ('a','a');") // ';' is wrong
```

use ,

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into utable values ('a','a')")
```

Comment: Yes. I noticed it right after clicking on 'Post your Question'! Thanks!